# Почему отрабатывает только true?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

Имеется такой код в контроллере Laravel:

```
public function put_in_favorites(Request $request)
$is_active = $request->get('is_active');      
    if ($is_active)
    {
       
            return 'this is true';
    }
    else
        {
            return 'this is false';
        }
```

Значение **$is_active** он получает из ajax-запроса:

```
$('.bpt-heart').on('click', function (){
        $(this).toggleClass('Active');
        let IsActive;
        if ($(this).hasClass('Active'))
        {
            IsActive = true;
        }
        else
        {
            IsActive = false;
        }
        dataId = this.getAttribute('data-id');
        // console.log(dataId);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'favorites',
        type: 'POST',
        headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
        data: {
            is_active: IsActive,
            data_id: dataId
        },
        success: function (data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (err)
        {
            console.log('Error');
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

Однако у меня всегда возвращается **this is true**, хотя если возвращать **$is_active** он, как и требуется, меняется на **true** и **false**.
Как сделать так, чтобы обрабатывались оба случая в контроллере в зависимости от переменной **$is_active**?

Comment: В дебаге проверьте, какое значение лежит в переменной непосредственно в момент проверки условий. Можете попробовать условие `$is_active=== true`

Comment: а там не строка случайно?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Посмотрите то, что отправляется через Network  в браузере. Скорее всего переменная передаётся в строком в виде. Поэтому она всегда `true`. Поэтому надо либо строгое сравнение делать, либо отправлять например непосредственно json  либо отправлять 1/0.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701146/191482  - отладку на стороне сервера сделать тоже очень полезно

Comment: а разве 0/1 не будут строкой тоже?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin просто потом они не явно вроде должны привестись к булевому в `if` )) если я ничего не путаю

Comment: это особенность php?)

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin ну, динамическая типизация ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ https://onlinephp.io/c/65cc7    .... в js например также должно быть

Comment: `let my_str ='0';

if(my_str){
    console.log(true)
}else{
    console.log(false)
}` в js true выдает так

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin и тут js подвёл :D

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение:

```
if ($is_active == 'true')
```

он её воспринимает в строковом виде.
Всем спасибо за ответы.

Comment: лол. ниже ответ вас не устроил?)

Comment: Так делать нельзя... вы тупо превратили булевое значение в строку)

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin, устроил, но я думал и так тоже можно делать...